# EasyMock 'Expected 1, Actual 1'

Tags: java, testing, junit, easymock

I'm currently having a problem with a Unit test using EasyMock.

```
Expectation failure on verify:
     FileConverter.convert(file, file2): expected: 1, actual: 1
```

This is the only failure in the class and it fails on the verify method below. I have tried to Google the message, but this only brings up results for "expected: 1, actual: 1 **(+1)**", and the **+1** implies the error is different.

I have tried to simplify the structure of the failing EasyMock test for demonstration. Please forgive any typos:

```
@Test
public void testScan() {
  String[] testFiles = { "file", "file2" };
  FileConverter converterMock = EasyMock.createMock(FileConverter.class);
  Poller poller = new Poller(new File("testFolder"), converterMock);

  for (String testFile : testFiles) {
    converterMock.convert(new File(testFile));
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
  }
  EasyMock.replay(converterMock);

  for (String testFile : testFiles) {
    poller.scan();
  }
  EasyMock.verify(converterMock);
}
```

I don't think the code itself is particularly relevant but I have included it for completeness - what I am really looking for is an explanation of what "expected 1, actual 1" could mean in the context of the EasyMock.verify method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you replace `once()` with `atLeastOnce()`?

Comment: I notice that you are expecting `convert(File)` but the error states if fails due to `convert(File, File)`. Is there a difference here or a type in the question?

Answer (score 5):

Another optional case is when using a multithreaded environment, it might occur that the desired method has invoked on the mock object after the test has already ended.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages can be very unclear from these test runs. I do see it fails on expecting a `convert` method call signature with 2 `File` arguments. So try expecting that by completing/replacing the following line in your test:

```
converterMock.convert(new File(testFile));
```

with something like:

```
File file1 = new File(testFile1);
File file2 = new File(testFile2);
converterMock.convert(testFile1, testFile2);
```

Also experiment with less specific matching like:

```
converterMock.convert(EasyMock.isA(File.class), EasyMock.isA(File.class));
```

or

```
File file1 = new File(testFile1);
File file2 = new File(testFile2);
converterMock.convert(EasyMock.eq(file1), EasyMock.eq(file2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a recent version of EasyMock? Because I do remember old version performing strange calculation sometimes.

I tried your code and if I guessed correctly the content of the scan method.

```
void scan(String file) {
    converter.convert(new File(file));
}
```

It should work perfectly.